# How to create a function that selects an array based on screen size

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website that will load a random image on page load. However, depending on the screen size, it will load from one of two arrays. I've set up a function to do this, but I keep getting a file not found error. How could I clean this up?

HTML:

```
<article id="maryKayQuote" class="d-flex flex-row my-5 clearfix">
     <div class="dailyQuoteText">
          <!-- This is where the random daily quote will appear -->
     </div>
     <div class="quoteBackgroundImage">
          <!-- This is where the random background image will appear. -->
     </div>
     <p class="dailyQuoteTextName">&#45;Mary Kay Ash</p>
</article>
```

JS:

```
var quoteBackground = document.querySelector('.quoteBackgroundImage');

var mkImagesLarge = [
     "images/Untitled.png",
     "images/Untitled2.png",
     "images/maryKay3.jpg",
     "images/maryKay4.png"
];

var mkImagesSmall = [
     "images/quote.jpg",
     "images/quote2.jpg",
     "images/quote3.jpg",
     "images/quote4.jpg"
];

function getRandomImage() {
     var img = '<img alt=\"An image of Mary Kay Ash.\" class=\"img-fluid\" 
         src=\"';
     var randomImg;
     var w = window.outerWidth;
     if (w => 1000) {
          randomImg += Math.floor(Math.random() * mkImagesLarge.length);
          img += mkImagesLarge[randomImg];
     } else if (w <= 500) {
          randomImg += Math.floor(Math.random() * mkImagesSmall.length);
          img += mkImagesSmall[randomImg];
     }
     img += '\">';
     return img;
};
```

Comment: `function getRandomImage() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    
     
     var w = window.outerWidth;
     if (w => 1000) {
          img.src = mkImagesLarge[Math.floor(Math.random() * mkImagesLarge.length)];
     } else if (w <= 500) {
         img.src = mkImagesSmall[Math.floor(Math.random() * mkImagesSmall.length)];
     }
    
     return img;
};`

then 
`quoteBackground.appendChild(getRandomImage());`

Comment: or in your code change `randomImg +=` with `randomImg = `

Comment: So the images popped up when I removed the equal sign but it is still evaluating it to the first condition on a small screen.

Answer (score 0):

So there was really just one big error with the code you provided. You were creating the image element by making a string and building it through that but that left a lot of room for error when adding the src property.

You should avoid creating elements as strings, you should instead create them through the `document.createElement('tagName');` method. More on this can be found here: [MDN Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

I believe the snippet below should work for your needs, you'll notice that if you refresh you'll see one of the images from the correct array show up in the snippet preview window.

If your browser complains about `const` and `let` you can switch them all to `var`.

```js
const quoteBackground = document.querySelector('.quoteBackgroundImage');

// As I don't have access to your images, I will be using placeholder ones:
const mkImagesLarge = [
    'https://placehold.it/100x100',
    'https://placehold.it/125x125',
    'https://placehold.it/150x150',
    'https://placehold.it/175x175',
];

// Again, same as with the large images but smaller ones this time.
const mkImagesSmall = [
    'https://placehold.it/10x10',
    'https://placehold.it/25x25',
    'https://placehold.it/50x50',
    'https://placehold.it/75x75',
];

/**
 * Get a random image from one of two arrays depending on the width
 * of the user's screen size.
 *
 * This does not create the image itself, just gets the src.
 *
 * @returns {string} The src attribte for the image when created.
 */
function getRandomImage() {

     let randomImg;
     
     let w = window.outerWidth;
     
     if (w >= 1000) {
     
          randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * mkImagesLarge.length);
          
          return mkImagesLarge[randomImg];
          
     } else if (w <= 500) {
     
          randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * mkImagesSmall.length);
          
          return mkImagesSmall[randomImg];
          
     }
     
}

/**
 * Handle the creation of the image here seperately because the image
 * has to be loaded asynchronously so we have to add it to the
 * document instead of returning it.
 *
 * @param {string} src The source of the image to create. This is from the `getRandomImage` function.
 */
function setRandomImage(src) {

    // Creating an image tag is preferred over using a string.
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.alt = 'An image of Mary Key Ash';
    img.classList.add('img-fluid');
    
    img.onload = function() {
    
      quoteBackground.appendChild(img);
    
    };
    
    img.src = src;

}

const backgroundImage = getRandomImage();

setRandomImage(backgroundImage);
```

```html
<article id="maryKayQuote" class="d-flex flex-row my-5 clearfix">
    <div class="dailyQuoteText">
        <!-- This is where the random daily quote will appear -->
    </div>
    <div class="quoteBackgroundImage">
        <!-- This is where the random background image will appear. -->
    </div>
    <p class="dailyQuoteTextName">&#45;Mary Kay Ash</p>
</article>
```

**UPDATE**:

In your comments you mentioned that it just shows 'HTMLImageElement' instead of the image which is to be expected because loading an image is asynchronous and snippet behaves differently than a live website.

To remedy this, instead of returning the image and using it later (would require creating a promise or using async/await and if you need that I can edit the snippet) we just add the photo to the document whenever it's loaded.

I've split the one function now into two so that it's easier to tell what's going on. `getRandomImage()` now just returns the source of the image that needs to be created and `setRandomImage()` will take that source and create an image element out of it and add it to the page whenever the image is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I ran the new snippet, it shows [object HTMLImageElement] instead of the picture. Not sure why that is haha. If you want I can push the files to my Gibhub if you need to take a better look at it. Here's the link to my repository https://github.com/rise-and-shane93/adenaMaryKay.